# How to pass data down the tree using flutter_blocs?

Tags: flutter, bloc, flutter-bloc

I am quite stuck on this thing for the past few days.

So my use case here is, 
A -> B -> C -> D

Update some data in A when there is some change in D.
A, B, C, D are different screens.

Now I understand we can give Two providers to the D using MultiBlocProvide.
but I am using the pushed name route, 
Not sure how to communicate here using blocs.

```
routes: {
  Routes.ScreenA: (context) => _getScreenA(),
  Routes.ScreenB: (context) => _getScreenB(),
  Routes.ScreenC: (context) => _getScreenC(),
  Routes.ScreenD: (context) => _getScreenD(),
}

  _getScreenA() {
    return BlocProvider<ScreenABloc>(
        create: (context) =>
            ScreenABloc(),
        child: ScreenARoute());
  }

  _getScreenB() {
    return BlocProvider<ScreenBBloc>(
        create: (context) => ScreenBBloc(),
        child: ScreenBRoute());
  }

  _getScreenC() {
    return BlocProvider<ScreenCBloc>(
        create: (context) => ScreenCBloc(),
        child: ScreenCRoute());
  }

  _getScreenD() {
    return BlocProvider<ScreenDBloc>(
        create: (context) => ScreenDBloc(),
        child: ScreenDRoute());
  }
```

Also checked the example of Todo's, but now sure how to plug it here.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than wrapping each route with `BlocProvider` wrap your `MaterialApp` on your `main.dart` file with `MultiBlocProvider` and then initialize all your required `bloc` classes there, They will be available everywhere on your application. If you are going to way define same `bloc` over different routes - there will be some data inconsistencies because you are not using same instance of a `bloc`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I can for sure do that, but do you think it is a god idea to expose Blocs to the entire widget tree.
I mean from the design point of view we are exposing the all the data in the entire application.